# Tomcat errors when we starting Spring MVC project

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am new to learning Spring MVC. My program listings are below. I have a controller in my `src/MySpringMVCProjects` folder. I get multiple markers of errors in the controller class, on the Exception, String and getParameter lines.

### Controller

```
package MySpringMVCProjects;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HelloController implements Controller {
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("msg", "Hello" + name);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("success", m);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <display-name>FirstMVCHelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>   
  </welcome-file-list>
  <!--  default -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HelloController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### Servlet xml : helloWorld-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
<!--  default handler mapping -->
<!--  handler -->
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
<!--  controller -->
<bean name = "/hello.htm" class = "MySpringMVCProjects.HelloController" />
<!--  view resolver -->
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name = "prefix" value ="/" />
        <property name = "suffix" value =".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

### index.jsp:

```
  <h1>HelloWorld</h1>
  <form action = "./hello.htm">
  NAME:<input type="text" value="name"/>
       <input type="submit"  value="sayHello"/>       
  </form>
```

### success.jsp:

```
${msg}
```

### Directory structure:

[image: project explorer view, page 1]
[image: project explorer view, page 2]

### Apache Tomcat error logs when running server:

```
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleWebService' did not find a matching property.
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FirstMVCHelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 19 2015 17:18:06 UTC
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.64.0
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_75-b13
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/amd64;C:\app\gafg\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\;C:\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle\bin\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\jdk1.7\bin;.;;C:\Users\gafg\Documents\Eclipse - Kepler\Eclipse-Kepler\eclipse;;.
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8001"]
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 852 ms
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\FirstMVCHelloWorld\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:16 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [111] milliseconds.
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:16 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SimpleWebService\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8001"]
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 09, 2015 1:25:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2439 ms
```

What is the error? How i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the server started properly.

From the project structure it looks like as you are unable to compile the project: **Reason being your have added Source files not the actual lib.**

You can check out some already available tutorial like:

- http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/
- http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

If you still face any problem, please paste the log entries from your log file
Can you please paste the error from Log4j or slf4j.